# How to tell if any kind of text field is focused?

Tags: autohotkey

Does AutoHotkey have a condition to tell if any text field (or Word document, browser search bar, anything with text input enabled) is currently focused? I want to use some hotkeys to type Unicode characters when it's possible and to perform other actions when it is not.

Comment: There is no easy way to see this - it depends on each case. You can examine this by using the AutoIt3 Windows Spy that comes with Autohotkey. Run it and then focus the text field and look at the Spy autoput. if it doesn't show significant changes then you will have problems and most of the times it is not worth trying. If it's just one piece of software you are trying to change here, it might be possible to do something with ImageSearch or similar hacks. One idea for example is to keep a screenshot, send one key that doesn't do anything outside a text box, do another screenshot and compare....

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example to get the currently focused control's name.

```
F1::
ControlGetFocus, OutputVar, A
if ErrorLevel
    MsgBox, The target window doesn't exist or none of its controls has input focus.
else
    MsgBox, Control with focus = %OutputVar%
```

This works on a good number of windows, but all in all it matters what type of controls the application uses as to whether it will return a value.